# Cumulative Counting in SQL

Tags: sql, distinct, cumulative-frequency

I am struggling to write a query that gets the cumulative distinct counts for values in a column.

```
table column:           desired column:
a                       1
b                       1
c                       1
c                       2
c                       3
a                       2
a                       3
```

Explanation:

`row 1` has value `a`, there are no preceding rows with value `a` so we count `a` once and get `1`.

`row 2` has value `b`, there are no preceding rows with value `b` so we count `b` once and get `1`.

`row 3` has value `c`, there are no preceding rows with value `c` so we count `c` once and get `1`.

`row 4` has value `c`, there is 1 preceding row with value `c` so we count `c` twice and get `2`.

`row 5` has value `c`, there are 2 preceding rows with value `c` so we count `c` thrice and get `3`.

`row 6` has value `a`, there is 1 preceding row with value `a` so we count `a` twice and get `2`.

`row 7` has value `a`, there are 2 preceding rows with value `a` so we count `a` thrice and get `3`.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of SQL supports it, then `ROW_NUMBER` is one option here:

```
SELECT
    col,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col ORDER BY col) cn
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

Note that the `ORDER BY` clause used above in `ROW_NUMBER` is arbitrary, since within a partition of column values, all would have the same value.